# Inline filtering in Angular using negation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to filter out records in an `ng-repeat` and having some difficulties.  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/th1PexQ3OdApdXAltCqC?p=preview) is a plunker.

Here is my code:

```
 $scope.userRoles = [
    { name: 'first user', role: { name: 'Agent' } }, 
    { name: 'second user', role: { name: 'Admin' } },
    { name: 'third user', role: { name: 'Super Admin' }
  }];

<li ng-repeat="userRole in userRoles | filter:{role.name:'!Agent'}">
  {{userRole.name}}
</li>
```

I should see "Admin" and "Super Admin" in my list, but it's throwing an exception I can't figure out.  I'm using Angular 1.4.3.  In the Angular docs, it says this is how you use negation in filtering.

Comment: Could you paste the exception you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just nest the properties, like so

```
<li ng-repeat="userRole in userRoles | filter:{ role: { name: '!Agent' }}">
    {{userRole.name}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's weird... it works without nesting in previous versions of Angular and I didn't see any documentation on this way.